# Logic Gates D Flip Flop

Tags: digital-logic

I'm using a program called Logisism and it has in-built features such as a D flip-flop:

[image]

However it doesn't show how it's actually made out of logic gates. Can someone *please* show me a diagram of have it is made. I've done some searching by get completely different results.

Thanks

Comment: What results have you got by searching? If you collect images of D flip-flop logic gate circuits and then ask clear questions about their differences I think you will get answers that are more likely to help you understand.

Comment: http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?genericPartNumber=sn74ls74a&fileType=pdf

Comment: Note that the TI design is the same as the one linked by Digital Dude if you remove the Set and Clear inputs.  I doubt if there is much variation.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#D_flip-flop)? Also it helps to understand the behavior of the device.  It stores one bit of data until it detects the rising edge of the clock, at which point it loads a new bit from the input.